# VS Extension - disabling errors from embedded code editor

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility

I want to show c# source code with syntax highlighting and theme coloring inside a wpf control. This is for preview only and I don't need any editing capabilities.

I found some code samples on how to embed a code editor which receives a file path to load.

I loaded it with a temp file I created - and it works, well almost...

The problem is that the loaded code have parsing errors which shows up in the error list.

Is there a way to set those errors to not appear in the error list?

Here is the code:

```
IVsInvisibleEditorManager invisibleEditorManager = (IVsInvisibleEditorManager)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsInvisibleEditorManager));

ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(invisibleEditorManager.RegisterInvisibleEditor(csTempFilePath, pProject: null,dwFlags: (uint)_EDITORREGFLAGS.RIEF_ENABLECACHING,
                                                                           pFactory: null, ppEditor: out this.invisibleEditor));

//The doc data is the IVsTextLines that represents the in-memory version of the file we opened in our invisibe editor, we need
//to extract that so that we can create our real (visible) editor.
IntPtr docDataPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
Guid guidIVSTextLines = typeof(IVsTextLines).GUID;
ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(this.invisibleEditor.GetDocData(fEnsureWritable: 1, riid: ref guidIVSTextLines, ppDocData: out docDataPointer));

try
{
    IVsTextLines docData = (IVsTextLines)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(docDataPointer);

    //Get the component model so we can request the editor adapter factory which we can use to spin up an editor instance.
    IComponentModel componentModel = (IComponentModel)ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
    IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService editorAdapterFactoryService = componentModel.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();

    //Create a code window adapter.
    this.codeWindow = editorAdapterFactoryService.CreateVsCodeWindowAdapter(OleServiceProvider);

    IVsCodeWindowEx codeWindowEx = (IVsCodeWindowEx)this.codeWindow;
    INITVIEW[] initView = new INITVIEW[1];
    codeWindowEx.Initialize((uint)_codewindowbehaviorflags.CWB_DISABLESPLITTER,
                             VSUSERCONTEXTATTRIBUTEUSAGE.VSUC_Usage_Filter,
                             szNameAuxUserContext: "",
                             szValueAuxUserContext: "",
                             InitViewFlags: 0,
                             pInitView: initView);

    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(this.codeWindow.SetBuffer((IVsTextLines)docData));

    //Get our text view for our editor which we will use to get the WPF control that hosts said editor.
    ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(this.codeWindow.GetPrimaryView(out this.textView));

    //Get our WPF host from our text view (from our code window).
    IWpfTextViewHost textViewHost = editorAdapterFactoryService.GetWpfTextViewHost(this.textView);

    textViewHost.TextView.Options.SetOptionValue(DefaultTextViewHostOptions.ChangeTrackingId, false);
    textViewHost.TextView.Options.SetOptionValue(DefaultTextViewOptions.ViewProhibitUserInputId, true);

    var dte = ContainerFactory.GetContainer().Resolve<DTE2>();
    var projectItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(csTempFilePath);
    projectItem.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = prjBuildAction.prjBuildActionNone;

    return textViewHost.HostControl;
}
finally
{
    if (docDataPointer != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        //Release the doc data from the invisible editor since it gave us a ref-counted copy.
        Marshal.Release(docDataPointer);
    }
}
```

I've tried to remove the errors from the error list manually. But it didn't work - I think it's because i can only remove errors that I added previously. Here is the code I tried using to remove the errors:

```
public void RemoveTempFileErrors()
{
    var provider = new ErrorListProvider(ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider)
        {
            ProviderName = "MyProvider",
            ProviderGuid = new Guid("41C0915D-A0F4-42B2-985F-D1CC5F65BFFC") // my provider guid
        };

    var vsTaskList1 = (IVsTaskList) Package.GetGlobalService(typeof (IVsTaskList));
    uint providerCookie;
    vsTaskList1.RegisterTaskProvider(provider, out providerCookie);

    vsTaskList1.RefreshTasks(providerCookie);

    var vsTaskList2 = (IVsTaskList2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(IVsTaskList));

    provider.SuspendRefresh();
    IVsEnumTaskItems enumerator;
    vsTaskList1.EnumTaskItems(out enumerator);
    IVsTaskItem[] arr = new IVsTaskItem[1];
    while (enumerator.Next(1, arr, null) == 0)
    {
        string doc;
        arr[0].Document(out doc);
        if (doc == csTempFilePath)
        {
            vsTaskList2.RemoveTasks(providerCookie, 1, arr);
        }            
    }

    provider.ResumeRefresh();
    provider.Refresh();
    vsTaskList1.UnregisterTaskProvider(providerCookie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it partially -

The parsing errors were caused because the code was a method without a class. So i wrapped the method in a class and used an elision buffer to show only the method without the wrapper class

The elision buffer code goes like this:

```
var subsetSnapshot = new SnapshotSpan(textSnapshot.Lines.First().EndIncludingLineBreak, textSnapshot.Lines.Last().Start);

var projectionBufferFactory = componentModel.GetService<IProjectionBufferFactoryService>();

var projBuffer = projectionBufferFactory.CreateElisionBuffer(null, 
new NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection(subsetSnapshot), ElisionBufferOptions.None);

IVsTextBuffer bufferAdapter = editorAdapterFactoryService.CreateVsTextBufferAdapterForSecondaryBuffer(OleServiceProvider, projBuffer);

projTextView = editorAdapterFactoryService.CreateVsTextViewAdapter(OleServiceProvider);

projTextView.Initialize((IVsTextLines)bufferAdapter, IntPtr.Zero, 
    (uint)TextViewInitFlags.VIF_HSCROLL | (uint)TextViewInitFlags.VIF_VSCROLL | (uint)TextViewInitFlags3.VIF_NO_HWND_SUPPORT,
    new[] { new INITVIEW { fSelectionMargin = 0, fWidgetMargin = 0, fVirtualSpace = 0, fDragDropMove = 0 } };

IWpfTextViewHost projTextViewHost = editorAdapterFactoryService.GetWpfTextViewHost(projTextView);
```